# Code works in Excel Modules but not in ThisWorkbook module.

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a very simple piece of VBA code to copy the value of a cell, open another workbook, and paste that cell value into the newly opened workbook. It works perfectly in a normal module. But when I run the code in the ThisWorkbook module, for the purpose of triggering it when the file is saved, the other workbook will not open. Simpler macros like opening a MsgBox work fine in ThisWorkbook, however. Another weird thing is that the code DOES work in ThisWorkbook if I am viewing the code. Anyone know why this might be happening? I'm running Excel 2010.

Code is below:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rangetocopy As String
Dim w1 As Workbook
Dim w2 As Workbook

Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook
Calculate

rangetocopy = w1.Sheets("Reference Data").Range("F10").Value

Set w2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Documents\To-Do.xlsm")

w2.Worksheets("Masterlist").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Value = rangetocopy

w1.Worksheets("To-do List").Activate

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Call the sub routine from the module when the events triggers.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint (F9) on the `Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook` line, and then hit Ctrl+S... does the breakpoint get hit? FWIW working with `Select` and `Activate` is far from ideal; consider figuring out other ways to do your thing.

Comment: Ryan - Tried that, didn't work. Good idea though.

Comment: Mat - I placed the breakpoint, hit Ctrl+S, and the code view opened up and that line was highlighted in yellow. Is that what you mean by getting hit?

Comment: I know that this code, or something similar at least, worked in a more recent version of Excel. I can't test it right now but I will later. I suspect this is just a bug in Excel 2010.

Comment: `Set w1 = ActiveWorkbook` should probably be `Set w1 = ThisWorkbook`  Are you seeing any error when the workbook doesn't get opened?

Comment: Tim, I changed the code as you suggested with no luck. I get a Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set, but it highlights the line `w2.Worksheets("Masterlist").Activate`, which comes after the command to open the other workbook. I think the error 91 simply says that I can't activate a worksheet in a book that failed to open. There's no error for failure to open the workbook - it just doesn't open it.

Comment: If the workbook fails to open then that should raise an error: the code should not then fail instead on the next line.  Maybe the workbook did open and you're not seeing it (is it hidden?) - does it appear in the project tree in the VB editor?  BTW I will get a notification if you include @timwilliams in your comment...

Comment: @timwilliams It doesn't appear in the tree. It's not minimized. Is there another place it could be "hidden"?  Also, the weird part is that if I open View Code, and THEN I hit Ctrl+S, the macro works perfectly.

Comment: I can't explain that: if the workbook opens then it should be there in the tree - if it doesn't open then that should have raised an error.  Try adding `MsgBox w2.Sheets.Count` directly after the `Open` line: what do you see when it runs?

Comment: @timwilliams I get the same `Error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set`. But now it highlights the new line you wrote. It's driving me crazy that the code works when the View Code window is open. if I could add a command that opens that view, runs the code, and closes that view, I would be all set. But I doubt that exists.

Comment: Is that the complete/exact code you're running?

Comment: @TimWilliams Fixed it. I had to disconnect a 3rd party add-in my firm uses. Not sure why it wasn't interfering when I ran the code outside of ThisWorkbook, without the beforesave trigger, but at least it works now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a 3rd party add-in called WorkSite. Once I disconnected from that, the macro worked fine.